# How to create this expression tree (Static method)?

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I want to create an expression tree object for `a => Math.Sin(a)` with the code below:

```
ParameterExpression a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Double), "a");
MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Math).GetMethod("Sin", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static),
    a);

LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, a);
Console.WriteLine(lambda);
```

But the result is always a => Sin(a)

I also tried

```
Expression<Func<Double, Double>> lambda = a => Math.Sin(a);
```

but get the same result.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: What is the actual issue here?  that the Console.WriteLine output isn't what you expect?  The lambda is filed and can be invoked without an issue.  You'll find that in any instance of a lambda invoking a static method, the class name is dropped when outputting to console.  On the flip side, the following `Expression<Func<bool, bool>> xx = abc => new Test().IsTrue(true);` outputs: `abc => new Test().IsTrue(True)`

Comment: I would like the console output to be  a => Math.Sin(a) instead of  a => Sin(a) . But as you said, the class name is dropped.

Comment: @yyou That's just the way they've decided to implement `ToString()`. Nothing you can do to change that. You'll need to write your own implementation which takes an Expression and outputs your desired format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to change the way you're representing an expression in plain text, this might give you a (very very messy and quick) start:

```
private string MyToString(Expression e)
{
    var lam = e as LambdaExpression;

    if (lam != null)
    {
        var pStr = lam.Parameters.Select(p => MyToString(p));
        var paramStr = pStr.Any() ? string.Format("({0})", string.Join(", ", pStr)) : "()";
        var bodyExpr = MyToString(lam.Body);
        return paramStr + " => "  + bodyExpr;
    }
    var param = e as ParameterExpression;
    if (param != null)
    {
        return param.Name;
    }
    var methodExpression = e as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodExpression != null)
    {
        string methodName;
        if (methodExpression.Method.IsStatic)
            methodName = methodExpression.Method.DeclaringType.Name + "." + methodExpression.Method.Name;
        else
            methodName = methodExpression.Method.Name;

        var pStr = methodExpression.Arguments.Select(p => MyToString(p));
        var paramStr = pStr.Any() ? string.Format("({0})", string.Join(", ", pStr)) : "()";

        return methodName + paramStr;
    }
    return e.ToString();
}
```

Called like:

```
ParameterExpression a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Double), "a");
MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Math).GetMethod("Sin", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static),
    a);

LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, a);

MyToString(lambda).Dump();
```

Gives:

```
(a) => Math.Sin(a)
```

Be aware though, if you *do* go down this path, you'll need to cover all edge cases, and you'll eventually find anything more than a simple expression will become more effort than it's worth.

That being said, you need to decide if this is really worth it, or if you can take an alternative approach.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize it takes so many steps to get the class name printed out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @yyou You're welcome. Be aware though, this only covers 3 expression types (and not entirely; it will be a bit wonky on an instance-method call). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx Has a list of the expression types available, and each one needs to be implemented if you want a fool-proof `ToString` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this on the net: https://github.com/JakeGinnivan/ExpressionToString/blob/master/src/ExpressionToString/ExpressionStringBuilder.cs

If you edit the VisitMethodCall to print class name for static method calls, it gives you what you want. This approach is closer to normal expression tree handling practices, since it uses a normal expressionvisitor, instead of a recursive single method.

I didnt write this code, just found it, but at first look it seems promising.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried the ExpressionToString and it works!

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [TryRoslyn](https://github.com/ashmind/TryRoslyn) in github which has a [playground](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/) site for Roslyn project.
In case you need to create an expression tree from your code, you just need to paste your code and see the output of the expression tree.
I've already made an [example](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AMpAI7ECiAHgA4BOqI4A9hCDvcAEYA2YAMYwh/AIasYAYRgBvbDCUweA4TABubMABMYAWQAUASnnYAkObpMW7CAB4AYsAhD7Otn36oANDA9eqAB8QTC8MAC8MOKRofriyAAWxHCQhuLGOMowAL7YOUAA=) of `Expression<Func<double, double>> b = a => Math.Sin(a);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's interesting! I will try that with my remaining expression trees creation.